# Using "Did" should it be followed by past or present tense verb?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, bare-infinitives

Did you woke up this morning and looked at the mirror, and notice the eye bags are puffer than ever?

Comment: What follows after do/does/did is an infinitive,  not present tense.

Comment: You seem to learn English without a grammar, which is a systematic introduction into the system of a language. You should try to find a grammar for beginners. Public libraries often have such things.

Answer (score 5):

StoneyB has given the right answer—it is neither the past tense nor the present tense, but the **bare infinitive** that follows.

However, this might be a little confusing, because with a second person subject, the infinitive looks the same as the present tense<sup><sup>†</sup></sup>!  So how can we tell the difference?

Let's change the subject from *you* to *he*.  With a third person singular subject, the infinitive and present tense look different:

```
Did he 
  wake up this morning and
  look in the mirror and
  notice his eyebags are puffier than ever?
```

Notice how it says *wake*, *look*, and *notice*.  These are the infinitive forms.  If you tried to use the present tense, it would be ungrammatical:

```
Did he 
  *wakes up this morning and
  *looks in the mirror and
  *notices his eyebags are puffier than ever?
```

Why does this happen?  Well, let's break this down:

> 1a. He **woke** up this morning.
> 1b. He **looked** in the mirror.
> 1c. He **noticed** his eyebags are puffier than ever.

In each case, the first (and only) verb in the main clause is past tense.  That's fine, but we'd like to turn these sentences into questions, and in order to do that, we need an auxiliary verb.  Let's add the dummy auxiliary *do*:

> 2a. He **did** wake up this morning.
> 2b. He **did** look in the mirror.
> 2c. He **did** notice his eyebags are puffier than ever.

Now each main clause has two verbs: *did wake, did look*, and *did notice*.  But as you can see, the second verb is no longer marked for tense!  In each case, the verb following *do* appears in its **bare infinitive** form.

In all three sentences, the tensed verb is *did*.  Having both verbs tensed would be ungrammatical, and that's true whether we put the second verb in past or present tense:

> *Past tense*
>
> 3a. He **did** **woke* up this morning.
> 3b. He **did** **looked* in the mirror.
> 3c. He **did** **noticed* his eyebags are puffier than ever.
>
> *Present tense*
>
> 4a. He **did** **wakes* up this morning.
> 4b. He **did** **looks* in the mirror.
> 4c. He **did** **notices* his eyebags are puffier than ever.

All of the examples in 3a-c and 4a-c are ungrammatical.

But the sentences we made earlier in 2a-2c are fine.  Let's take them and turn them into questions by swapping the subject *he* with the auxiliary *did*:

> 2a. *He* **did** wake up this morning.
> 2b. *He* **did** look in the mirror.
> 2c. *He* **did** notice his eyebags are puffier than ever.
>
> ↓　↓　↓　↓　↓　↓
>
> 5a. **Did** *he* wake up this morning?
> 5b. **Did** *he* look in the mirror?
> 5c. **Did** *he* notice his eyebags are puffier than ever?

One last thing.  We'll join these sentences together with *and*:

```
    Did he wake up this morning
and did he look in the mirror
and did he notice his eyebags are puffier than ever?
```

And now we've got your sentence, pretty much.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup></sup>Except if the verb is *be* or defective.

In this answer, the * symbol marks a verb form as ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4):

*Do* is the tensed verb in this construction, and it takes an *infinitive*. For all verbs except *be* this is the same form as the uninflected present, so

> Did you  **wake** up this morning and
>                 **look** in the mirror and
>                 **notice** your eyebags are puffier than ever?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use present tense if you were asking.

'Did you **wake** up this morning and **look** in the mirror and notice your eyebags **were** bigger then ever?

But if you were stating this then you would say it in past tense.

'I **woke** up this morning and **looked** in the mirror and noticed my eyebags **are** bigger then ever.